# How to load some data into $rootScope from remote server before the module's controller is loaded?

Tags: angularjs

My module has a controller that depends on `$rootScope.foo`, which is populated by the use of `$http` service. **My question is how I can make sure `$rootScope.foo` is populated before the controller is loaded.**

I tried with loading `$rootScope.foo` in the module's `run()` method:

```
myModule.run(function($rootScope, $http, $location) {
  $http.get("http://mydomain/load_user/").
    success(function(respData) {
      $rootScope.foo = respData.foo;
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work as the controller gets loaded before the code inside of `success()`.

Answer (score 9):

The `$http` service is implemented using promises.

The code you write in your `success` handler will run when the promise is resolved. Due to the asynchronous nature of promises, it is unknown when this happens. It can be 1 second later or 10 seconds later.

Meanwhile, your other code continues to run and your controller is probably getting loaded before the promise is resolved.

The best way to tackle this problem is to think in 'asynchronous' terms, not force some kind of synchronous behavior.

Here are a few valid options:

1. You could move the code to your controller and move your logic to the success handler like this:

   ```
   myModule.controller('SomeCtrl', function($rootScope, $http, $location) {
     $http.get("http://mydomain/load_user/").
       success(function(respData) {
         // Perform any logic you need here and use respData.foo;
       });
   });
   ```
2. Another approach is to use events to notify your controller when the promise has been resolved (and the data has been loaded from the server) like this:

   ```
   myModule.run(function($rootScope, $http, $location) {
     $http.get("http://mydomain/load_user/").
       success(function(respData) {
         $rootScope.foo = respData.foo;

         // Broadcast event that foo was updated
         $rootScope.$broadcast('fooWasUpdated'); 
       });
   });
   ```

   Then in your controller you can add a listener for the event:

   ```
   myModule.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {

     $scope.$on('fooWasUpdated', function(event){
       // Perform your logic with $rootScope.foo
     });

   });
   ```
3. A third way is to not use the `$rootScope`at all but use the event to notify the listeners and pass the data around with the event like this:

   ```
   myModule.run(function($rootScope, $http, $location) {
     $http.get("http://mydomain/load_user/").
       success(function(respData) {
         // Broadcast event that foo was updated
         // You can add data as extra arguments
         $rootScope.$broadcast('fooWasUpdated', respData.foo); 
       });
   });
   ```

   Then in your controller you can add a listener for the event:

   ```
   myModule.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {

     $scope.$on('fooWasUpdated', function(event, foo){
       // Perform your logic with foo instead of $rootScope.foo
     });

   });
   ```

   You can find more detailed info about `$broadcast` and `$on` in the [AngularJS documentation for scopes](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope).

A few benefits of using events are:

- you can have multiple listeners in your applications listening to the same event
- you don't have to worry about being in the right scope in AngularJS
- you don't necessarily have to store data in a scope to make it available elsewhere

Hope that helps!